# Passing JSON data on uiviewTable ios (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview

There are similar questions but i could not find any solution which fits for me. 
I have got all the data from the link as `JSON` but i am unable to understand that how can i show that data on uitableview. It is to be shown on homepage. it has `title`, `info`. for now i only need `title` and `info` to be shown on homepage.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mantis.vu.edu.pk/fundme/public/api/v1/ideas"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *jsonOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
    {
        NSDictionary *responseDict = (NSDictionary *)JSON;
        ideasArrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       for (NSDictionary *innerObject in [responseDict objectForKey:@"data"])
           {
              [ideasArrayList addObject:innerObject];
       if (ideasArrayList.count > 0) {
          NSDictionary *userObject = [ideasArrayList objectAtIndex:0];
          NSLog(@"Object and first index of array is %@",userObject);
       }
       failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
                                             {

 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops something went wrong."
 message:[error localizedDescription]
 delegate:nil
 cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
 otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alertView show];

  }];
  [jsonOperation start];
```

i am using `AFNetworking` library.

Comment: can you preview the `innerObject`

Comment: add the value of `userObject` or `innerObject` in question. and add `cellforrowatindexpath` method also that you have tried!!

Comment: Use NSnotificationCenter and pass whole dictionary data where you want to show and parse data accordingly as you want.

Comment: You will be getting all your response data in ideasArrayList. From that Mutable array you can get the values for ideas_title as [ideasArrayList Valueforkey:@"idea_title"].

Answer (score 0):

if you call your code in ViewController, at first you need add a `dispatch_async` block for move your data to main thread and reload tableview

```
-(void)getDataFromApi {

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mantis.vu.edu.pk/fundme/public/api/v1/ideas"];
   NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   AFJSONRequestOperation *jsonOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
    {
        NSDictionary *responseDict = (NSDictionary *)JSON;
        ideasArrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       for (NSDictionary *innerObject in [responseDict objectForKey:@"data"])
           {
              [ideasArrayList addObject:innerObject];
       if (ideasArrayList.count > 0) {
          NSDictionary *userObject = [ideasArrayList objectAtIndex:0];
          NSLog(@"Object and first index of array is %@",userObject);

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              self.ideasArrayList = ideasArrayList;
              [self.tableView reloadData];
          });

       }
       failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
           {
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops something went wrong."
                message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
               [alertView show];
          });
  }];
  [jsonOperation start];
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

And implement `UITableViewDatasource` protocol methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  {
    return self.ideasArrayList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //configure the cell here or create custom subclass
    }

    NSDictionary *innerObject = self.ideasArrayList[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = innerObject[@"title"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `self.tableView.dataSource = self;` throws error `property tableView not found on type ` **HomeVC**

Comment: If you wanna display your data in tableView, you need create it in your ViewController

Comment: got it! after making it. How can i display it on other contorller? i want to show it on `HomeVC` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's help for you.

First you want to add the `.m` file.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "tblcellTableViewCell.h"
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *arrJSONDATA;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tbl;

@end
```

and add the below code the `viewDidLoad`.

```
arrJSONDATA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mantis.vu.edu.pk/fundme/public/api/v1/ideas"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *err;
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&err];
    NSDictionary *dicData = [dic valueForKey:@"data"];
    for (NSDictionary *dic1 in dicData) {
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arr addObject:[dic1 objectForKey:@"idea_title"]];
        [arr addObject:[dic1 objectForKey:@"idea_info"]];

        [arrJSONDATA addObject:arr];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",[arrJSONDATA description]);
    [_tbl reloadData];
```

Label Outlet Create for `title` and `info`.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tblcellTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblInfo;
@end
```

Then Create the `tableView` Delegate Method.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [arrJSONDATA count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tblcellTableViewCell *cells = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arr = [arrJSONDATA objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cells.lblTitle.text = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    cells.lblInfo.text = [arr objectAtIndex:1];

    return cells;
}
```

[[Check the Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gFgx.png)]

Comment: i got the data in this way but how can i view this data in uiViewTable?

Comment: Where to put last snippet of code? and there is no 'tblCellTableViewCell.h' what to do with it

Comment: You Prefer this link http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/customize-table-view-cells-uitableview-ios ... Create the tableViewCell file then select the tableview and select the cell and import the class files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the values you need to display in tableview in an array. So retrieve those values from your output JSON and store them in an array. Then in the data source methods of table view follow the usual.For e.g.- In the numberOfRowsInSection return yourArray.count. I hope you get the point.

I hope you get the point. Store values in array and then make the table fetch from that array.

Comment: I have done it already. check `ravi's answer`. i just want to show it on uiTableView. which i am unable to do.